# Enum data efficiency with strings in Rust

Tags: rust, data-structures, memory-management, enums, heap-memory

I am currently working with a vec of an enum which contains immutable strings for some of the variables. This has led me to a slight problem of data ineffeciency as the smaller variants take up 1 less memory adrress and this smaller variant will be the vast majority of the Vec. As this code may at some point be used to handle a vector of some huge unforseen size this extra memory address could be important.

```
pub enum Term {
    Constant(Box<str>),
    QUVar(usize),    //Query Variable
    EQVar(Box<str>), //Existentialy Quantified Variable
    AQVar(Box<str>), //Universally Quantified Variable
}
let mut heap:Vec<Term> = Vec::with_capacity(MAX_HEAP_SIZE);
```

My first thought was to use Box<Box> instead as this means i'm only wasting 8 bytes but the trade of there would likely be lower performance as i'd be working with a double reference.

I guess in my mind the best case is some heap pointer in which the first value is the length of the str as a usize, and then the subsequent addresses on the heap are the characters of the str.

Any ideas on how to balance this tradeoff between memory and performance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: A quick search yields the [thin_str](https://docs.rs/thin_str) crate which looks like exactly what you want (though version 0.1.0 and non-existent downloads may dissuade some). There is also the [`ThinBox`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.ThinBox.html) type from the standard library. It is not yet stabilized but is probably an excellent choice if using the nightly compiler isn't a worry.

Comment: Can you use `Box<&str>` instead? `Box`s around a raw slice are double-sized to know both location and size, but `Box`s around a reference to a slice are just a pointer (because they point to a slice that knows its size natively). `Box::new("someliteral")` is already creating a `Box<&str>`, so if you're sharing `str` literals, that works fine. If they're not literals, you probably want the `Box` to own them anyway, so maybe `Box<String>` in that case?

Comment: Some questions: 1) Is the order of terms important? 2) Does your `QUVar` (the small variant in your example) represent the same sort of semantic object as the other variants (owing to the fact that it has a `usize`, which I'm assuming might be better declared as a `u64`)? 3) Do you expect with reasonably high probability that the strings in your other three variants are going to be unique?

Comment: @ShadowRanger That would be a double reference, which is exactly what OP is trying to avoid. I agree that this would be the most ergonomic way to do it, though, if OP eventually goes with that route.

Comment: @TheHans255: Yar. I am concerned this is wildly premature optimization; if the `Vec` has 10M slots in it, and they're *all* `QUVar`, the waste here is on the order of 80 MB of memory (on top of 80 MB "useful" memory for the `Vec`, plus the memory for the strings), which isn't the end of the world. A two-step pointer dereference costs more than one step, but unless the cost is dereferencing these things for >5% of the workload, *and* doing nothing of consequence with the result of the dereferencing (seems unlikely; `str` are likely displayed or copied), the incremental cost doesn't matter.

Comment: In particular, if `QUVar` are the vast majority of the values as stated, then worrying about the cost of an extra pointer dereference for the non-`QUVar` values, when it presumably won't *happen* very often, seems rather overblown.

Comment: Notice that due to simple memory fragmentation, the net-gain of `Box<Box<_>>` is probably negative. One might calculate a theoretical top-line gain, but the allocator has to keep track of all those pointers, and you don't see that effect, unless you actually measure it.
Besides: As the strings are immutable, consider using an `Rc<str>` instead of individual `Box<str>` to de-duplicate the allocations. My guess is there is much more to be gained there.

Comment: On second thought, `ThinBox` wouldn't work out. I can't see a sane way that you'd make a `ThinBox<str>` using the provided API.